# SFML Fill Image pixel by pixel

Tags: c++, sfml

The function computePixelColor returns 0xFFFFFF.

It should be white but it is black.

_window is a sf::RenderWindow.

I've read that the texture object stores the color as RGBA.

I can't find what is the error in my following code, any help would be appreciated:

```
void Window::run(const Parser &parser) {
  sf::Event event;
  sf::Texture texture;
  sf::Vector2u size = _window.getSize();
  std::uint8_t *pixels = new std::uint8_t[4 * size.y * size.x];
  texture.create(size.x, size.y);
  sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

  Rt rt(parser.getCamera(), parser.getObjects());
  unsigned int color;
  unsigned int pos;

  while (_window.isOpen()) {
    _window.clear();
    pos = 0;
    while (_window.pollEvent(event)) {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        _window.close();
    }
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
      for (unsigned int x = 0; x < size.x; ++x) {
        color = rt.computePixelColor(x, y);
        pixels[4 * pos] = (color >> 4) & 0xFF;
        pixels[4 * pos + 1] = (color >> 2) & 0xFF;
        pixels[4 * pos + 2] = color & 0xFF;
        pixels[4 * pos + 3] = 0;
        ++pos;
      }
    }
    texture.update(pixels);
    _window.draw(sprite);
    _window.display();
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set the alpha channel to `0xFF`, instead of 0?

Comment: That's it, thank you for your time

Comment: Also, why are you shifting down by 4 for the red component, and 2 for the green component? Shouldn't that be 16 and 8?

Comment: Yes it should, just outdated code that i leaved their cause it had no concequences